# Input Field Values still appearing after clearing session storage and local Storage in Log Out in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am clearing sessionStorage and localStorage when user has clicked Log out button but when user Logs in again the input field values reappear to the values stored before the log out. Please help me resolve this problem.

The user when logs in after refreshing the page the input fields appear empty but when logs in without refreshing the page the values don't disappear.
After debugging I found that props value is not getting initialized.

Here's what I'm using for clearing storage -

```
Log out - 
    logout() {
        window.document.clear();
        window.sessionStorage.removeItem('acesstToken');
        sessionStorage.clear();
        localStorage.clear();
        this.setState({ logout: 'true'})
    }


After Login First Page - 

     constructor(props) {
           super(props);
           this.state = {
                name = '',
           }

           // This is called whenever user returns from next page to this page. This is not exactly the same code.
           this.state.name = this.props.name;
     }

     render() {
         return (
             <label className="control-label">Name</label>
                    <input type="text" defaultValue={this.state.name}  />
         );
     }
```

Comment: HAVe you tried without window like localStorage.clear(); ?

Comment: Yes, I've tried but not working

Comment: Ok. Wr exactly you doing that I mean you need to share the code of the logout and input fields component

Comment: Ok, I updated it a little. I hope its what you want.

Comment: Never mutate state directly, you can directly assign name when you are initialising the state. this.state = {
                name = this.props.name
           }. Regarding your problem From which component you are sending name i.e., this.proos.name?

Comment: There is actually next button below with which he will go to next component (another form basically) and when he clicks back button he returns back to this component and when he returns the input field populates with the value he previously used before going to next component. And thanks for telling me state mutating thing.